# How to connect HP MSA2324sa to server?

Tags: linux, storage, hp, hp-smart-array

I'm having issues with an HP MSA2324sa array. I connected it to the server and the server does see it however, I am not getting a /dev/s* device even though I have properly mapped the host from the SMU. I am able to see the following in dmesg:

```
scsi 1:0:2:0: Enclosure         HP       MSA2324sa        M114 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi 1:0:2:0: SSP: handle(0x0009), sas_addr(0x500c0ffd8f54f200), phy(4), device_name(0x0000000000000000)
scsi 1:0:2:0: SSP: enclosure_logical_id(0x500605b00a11c050), slot(5)
scsi 1:0:2:0: qdepth(254), tagged(1), simple(1), ordered(0), scsi_level(6), cmd_que(1)
ses 1:0:2:0: Attached Enclosure device
ses 1:0:2:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
```

When running lsscsi however I get the following:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   4.68  /dev/sda 
[0:0:0:1]    disk    HP       LOGICAL VOLUME   4.68  /dev/sdb 
[0:3:0:0]    storage HP       P420i            4.68  -       
[1:0:2:0]    enclosu HP       MSA2324sa        M114  -       
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       DVD A  DU8A5SH   NHJ3  /dev/sr0
```

It doesn't even show when I run lsblk:

lvdisplay and vgdisplay also don't show it.

The kernel module is loaded:

I was on the phone with HP support and shared the screen with them and they confirmed that I have properlyconfigured/mapped the storage array. The OS I'm running is CentOS 6.5:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
$ uname -r
2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
```

It is connected to the storage array using a SAS cable. Does anyone know what might be wrong or how can I go about mounting the array? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are missing the *"what happened before you asked this question?"* information.

The HP MSA2324sa is not a new product, so is this a used device? How did you get it? Where did you get it from?

All you need to do is create your volumes on the MSA in the SMU. Then map those to the server over controller(s). What type of HBA(s) are you using?

Did you reboot?

Is there anything in `fdisk -l`?

---

Is there *any* chance you configured the LUNs *after* booting the server?

Can you try rescanning the SCSI bus with something like:

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

Comment: Sorry for missing this. The storage array was functional 1 year ago and then the PSUs failed so it was decomissioned for a while. I joined the company 5 months ago and they decided to buy new PSUs and attach them to a different server. We are 100% confident it should work. I'm using HP 221 and the server was rebooted. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear when doing fdisk -l. Mny thanks

Comment: This is going to be a configuration issue... In the LSI/H221 BIOS, make sure the LUNs and enclosure are both detected. That will confirm if your selective storage presentation was done correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can this be done without rebooting the server? It is a very important server and it's only rebooted once a year.

Comment: No. You need to configure this from the system BIOS before the system boots. Can you `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` ?

Comment: Ok, cool. What would I be looking for in particular? Do you happen to have any screenshots?

Comment: Sorry for missing that. Here you go: http://pastebin.com/de2hw18e

Comment: I don't know what you should look for... make sure you see a SCSI disk or volume presented in the LSI controller BIOS. You may want to post screenshots of your SMU setup, because as-is, all I see is that the enclosure is connected. It seems like the SAS presentation is not working.

Comment: Try rescanning the SCSI bus... `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` - You may need to change the "host0" field.

Comment: I tried that but no go - here are the screenshots: http://imgur.com/xYK5Coy & http://imgur.com/N27D1D7

Comment: Oups, it seems that I replied to your previous question and didn't see the one with the rescanning the bus. I was able to run grep mpt /sys/class/scsi_host/host?/proc_name and then I ran the command you gave me for host1 and that worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I did but it doesn't display because I need a reputation of 15+ P.S. If that's not the way to do it please let me know how and I'll be glad to mark it.

Comment: @Mugurel To accept an answer, click the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green.